# Is there an Inhibit Sleep indicator for Unity?

Tags: 11.04, 12.04, unity, indicator, sleep

In the classic Gnome shell, you could add an Inhibit applet to prevent the computer going to sleep. This doesn't work with Unity. Is there an alternative and just easy way to prevent the computer temporarily following sleep power options? The Inhibit panel applet was as simple as a click.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use **caffeine**. It provides an indicator which used to work on 10.10 and 10.04. However I haven't tried it on Ubuntu 11.04.

**Brief Intro**

Caffeine is a nice little app indicator and does what its functions perfectly. It is lightweight and easy to install using the PPA given below. It has a intelligent screensaver/ sleep inhibiting mechanism. You can give it specific applications which while running should inhibit all power saving mechanism.

You can get more info on caffeine [here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/06/how-do-you-use-caffeine-the-app-not-the-stimulant/) and [here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/01/the-omg-guide-to-must-have-indicator-applets/).

Simply to install it in Natty, open the terminal and type the following command,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:caffeine-developers/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install caffeine
```

**Note**: In the second link above, it provides a list of all the additional indicators you can install. Search for caffeine in that list. There it says it does provide support for Natty as well. However since I haven't tried it personally I cannot guarantee it.

Comment: This is better than the classic applet! Lets me add specific programs. Perfect, thank you!

Comment: you are welcome :). Does it work properly in natty? I just installed it, however the options displayed on the caffeine indicators were not responsive...

Comment: As far as I know, there haven't been any packages created for Natty yet. I've been unable to reach the maintainer, but I hope there will be packages built by the time Natty is released.

Comment: Seems to work here. I haven't added any programs into it, but I can see the Preferences and use its disable screen saver function.

Comment: Caffeine is excellent, and Natty packages are available now.